# Thermodynamics - Property Tables

Tags: thermodynamics

I had a quick question regarding a homework problem. I cannot seem to understand why we are using internal energy of evaporation for this problem, instead of just using the internal energy of vapour to find the dryness fraction? Any help is appreciated!
Thank you
[image: Problem]

Comment: I will check upon you Q. Can you please share the name of textbook.

Comment: Edit your Q by making it simpler to understand. Users will then be interested in answering your Q.